# Hibernate with Primary Key in PostgreSQL with camelCase Format

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have this tables with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE "tblChecks"
(
  "checkId" serial NOT NULL,
  "bankId" text,
  "checkNumber" text,
  amount numeric(30,2)
)
```

Im using hibernate to make transactions on the database  my problem is 
with the insertion of the data. I have already mapped my 
model  with the following annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"tblChecks\"")
public class Check {

    /* Integereger values*/
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "\"checkId\"")
    private Integer checkId;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Double amount;

    /* String  values*/
    @Column(name = "\"bankId\"")
    private String bankId;

    @Column(name = "\"checkNumber\"")
    private String checkNumber;
```

In my insertion method there is an error that occurred

> ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The column name "checkId" was not found in this ResultSet.

My question is  how i can i fix these error on my primary key using Postgres. Changing the column name into checkid will fix the error, but  I cant do it because the tables are already in used with the current system.

Comment: Another good example why it's a bad idea to use quoted identifiers.

Comment: why are you using quotes in the column name? just remove them and your issue will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First thing wrong I found in your POJO is that you are using Auto Increment in PostgresSQL. This is not support by hibernate 3.x to 4.2. Therefore, you are not able to insert a record in database and may be getting an exception so called `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not retrieve generated id after insert:`
Instead of that you can use `serial` or `sequence`. [Serial Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

**Updated POJO class:** I have used sequence to generate entity ids and achieved same functionality as of auto_increment.

```
package stack.filter;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"tblChecks\"")
public class Check implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* Integereger values */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="checkId_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="checkId_seq", sequenceName="checkId_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "\"checkId\"")
    private Integer checkId;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Double amount;

    /* String values */
    @Column(name = "\"bankId\"")
    private String bankId;

    @Column(name = "\"checkNumber\"")
    private String checkNumber;

    public Integer getCheckId()
        {
            return checkId;
        }

    public void setCheckId(Integer checkId)
        {
            this.checkId = checkId;
        }

    public Double getAmount()
        {
            return amount;
        }

    public void setAmount(Double amount)
        {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

    public String getBankId()
        {
            return bankId;
        }

    public void setBankId(String bankId)
        {
            this.bankId = bankId;
        }

    public String getCheckNumber()
        {
            return checkNumber;
        }

    public void setCheckNumber(String checkNumber)
        {
            this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
        }
}
```

**Main Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Check c1=new Check();
        c1.setAmount(40555.4);
        c1.setBankId("AC11112");
        c1.setCheckNumber("CK12222CD");

        Check c2=new Check();
        c2.setAmount(50555.4);
        c2.setBankId("AC11111");
        c2.setCheckNumber("CK12233EW");

        session.persist(c1);//Insert check object c1
        session.persist(c2);//Insert check object c2

        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("After commit");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn’t roll back transaction"+ rbe);
       }
        throw e;
    } finally{
        if(session != null){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml file:** Make sure `hibernate.dialect` is `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property><!-- com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property> <!-- jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/postgres?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property><!-- postgres -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property><!-- postgres -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> 
    <mapping class="stack.filter.Check"/>
</session-factory>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: I have tried your answer but still it generates the same error when submitting the form. thank u for answering

Comment: Ok, I have tried this in MySQL & it worked fine. now I'm installing PostgreSQL, will be back soon.

Comment: because the mysql is not a case sensitive. The only thing I wonder was that I only generate an error on insertion but not on selecting data

Comment: Thank you so much Rohit Galkwad  now my code is working your such an amazing man!!!

Comment: A like for this please.