# Hibernate generates invalid DDL (PostgreSQL 9.6)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot JPA with no dialect configured in application.properties.
In my output, I can see that Hibernate is generating the following DDL commands:

```
create table user 
(
   id int8 not null, 
   password varchar(255), 
   username varchar(255), 
   primary key (id)
)
```

Which leads to a syntax error, because the table name must be enclosed within quotation marks.

That's my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springtest
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: `user` is a reserved word (keyword) Try another name (or quote it `CREATE TABLE "user" ...` )

Comment: Don't use names that would require quoting, even if you can convince your obfuscation layer to do so. You will get many more problems when using reserved keywords as identifiers

Comment: *obfuscation layer* is indeed the correct term. For example: how often do you see syntax-highlghting getting it wrong? Just don't trust on it. Don't rely on it. It is breakage waiting to happen. IMnsHO

Comment: @wildplasser: isn't ORM the abbreviation for "Obfuscated Relational Model"? (SCNR)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using reserved JPQL keywords with JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153881/using-reserved-jpql-keywords-with-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table name in quotes.
Here is one of the fine [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698973/hibernate-with-primary-key-in-postgresql-with-camelcase-format/39703583#39703583) which I have solved. The answer contains everything that you need.